# Navigating through Fragments in android without adding it into backstack

Tags: java, android, fragment

I'm working with android applications. I'm facing the issue like fragments adding in the back stack History. Let Me explain clearly, I want to navigate from Fragment A to Fragment B, then come back to Fragment A using button click in the Fragment B. Above scenario working good, after this navigation to Fragment A when i click back arrow in my device it navigates to the Fragment B. I don't want this to happen. Give me a solution. My code structure is below:

Fragment A:

```
.......
FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
showFragmentOmitStack(fragmentB);
....


public void showFragmentOmitStack(Fragment fragment) {
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 transaction.add(R.id.container,fragment);//add // replace
 transaction.addToBackStack(null);
 transaction.commit();
}
```

Fragment B:

```
FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
showFragment(fragmentA, "FragmentA");


public void showFragment(Fragment fragment, String back_stack_name) {
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = thisActivity.getFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment);
 fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(back_stack_name);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

In My Activity java file:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
 DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
 if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
     drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
   } else {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
      showAlertDialog(Constants.EXIT_APP, Constants.APP_NAME);
     } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you click the button in fragment B, don't add a new fragment A, just pop the backstack. The way you do it your backstack becomes A B A.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't intend to go back to the previous fragment with a back press just don't add the fragment to the backStack when you add the fragment, i.e. remove this:

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(myFragmentName);
```

Each fragment has it's own transaction, so when you add A with `addToBackStack`, thats reffering to fragment A! In fragment B transaction you set it to null, you are saying that B won't go in the backs tack. So the only fragment in the back stack that will be affected by the back press is A!

Comment: yes i made it null transaction.addToBackStack(null); when from the Fragment A to Fragment B call.

Comment: I want Fragment B not to add in backStack

Comment: NO! Each fragment has it's own transaction, so when you add A with addToBackStack, thats refering to fragment A! In fragment B transaction you set it to null, you are saying that B won't go in the backStack. So the only fragment in the backstack that will be affected by the back press is A!

Comment: From my understanding you don't want any of them in backstack, the reason I just told you to remove that line. Try it and test it

Comment: yes but i want only Fragment B not to add in backstack, other fragments have to add in it.

Comment: Then you need to think of a better solution. Implement an interface to handle onBackPressed in each fragment. There is plenty of example in SOF

Comment: The last part of this answer is incorrect. Passing null to addToBackStack still adds the fragment to the back stack. See here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }else {
       if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
           drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
         } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the button click the event that you have set on Fragment B that moves you back to Fragment A from there just remove the

```
yourTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

And you shall be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with only two Fragments, A and B, then you could do something like this:

In your **Activity**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
  } 
  else if (currentFragment instanceOf FragmentB) {
    Fragment fragmentA = new FragmentA();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentA);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    currentFragment = fragmentA;
  }  
  else {
       super.onBackPressed();
      }
  }
}
```

Instead of adding to the back stack, just create an instance variable in your class: `Fragment currentFragment = null;`. And then just keep setting currentFragment to the fragment you started.

Answer (score 0):

`addToBackStack(null)` still adds Fragment B to the back stack. The null parameter is just the name of the back stack state. You should remove that line in your `showFragmentOmitStack` method if you don’t want the fragment to be added to the back stack.

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)